# Timeout when accessing web service from Gradle on GitHub action runner

Tags: gradle, github-actions

I'm trying to run integration tests through Gradle in a GitHub action, but they time out. If I try to access the endpoint from `curl`, it works nicely but if I do the very same `GET` from Gradle, it times out.

So this works:

```
- name: Check endpoints
  run: |
    curl http://host.domain:31000/somePath/
```

But this times out:

```
- name: Run integration tests
  run: ./gradlew --no-daemon -Pserver_url=http://host.domain:31000 :intTest --tests ConnectTest
```

That test is created to chase this issue and it just does a `GET`

Anybody an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the port numbers in the URLs. We've implemented a reverse proxy and replaced the ports with domain names. Now it works as expected.
I have created a bug report for GitHub. Once they respond, I will share their response here.